# Can we use that/those of before a possessive?

Tags: sentence-construction

I wonder whether these sentences are correct or not:

> - My fingers are smaller than **those of** my brother's.
> - You can borrow my note or **that of** Sandy's.

I don't know, but the second just sounds awkward. Are those sentences acceptable? I'm trying to avoid repeating the noun that has written in the front. Or probably you have another suggestion as to how to write the noun one time? Please add your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: The most natural way is to omit both phrases in bold: "My fingers are smaller than my brother's" and "You can borrow my note or Sandy's".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are grammatical, but they don't mean what I think you want them to mean. The first sentence would be interpreted thus:

> My fingers are smaller than those of my brother's [[fingers]].

(I use double brackets to indicate text that would often be elided.) Obviously, that doesn't make sense. Possible fixes include:

> My fingers are smaller than my brother's [[fingers]].
> My fingers are smaller than those of my brother.

The second sentence would be interpreted thus:

> You can borrow my note or that of Sandy's [[note]].

Obviously, that doesn't make sense. Possible fixes include:

> You can borrow my note or Sandy's [[note]].
> You can borrow my note or that of Sandy. (<-- uncommon)

Comment: I see. So, I don't need the extra ('s) when I use [that/those + of]?

Comment: It depends on your intended meaning. Whenever you write a possessive without the following word (i.e., the word that it would modify), ask yourself what that following word would be and insert it there and see whether the sentence makes sense.

Comment: For example, this would be correct: "The skyscrapers of Hong Kong's business district are taller than those of Rome's [[business district]]."

Comment: I disagree that the OP's sentences are grammatical; they are only correct with one or other of your options.

Comment: @KateBunting Can you explain what makes them ungrammatical?

Comment: Apologies - I began to have my doubts as soon as I had logged out yesterday morning. It seemed to me on first reading that it had to be either _my brother's [fingers]_ or _the fingers of my brother_.